# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'intersys.pythonbind31'

Tags: python, intersystems

I want to connect cache database to python, but a problem occurred to me, I can `import intersys`,  but I can't `import intersys.pythonbind3`.there's an error showed like this ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'intersys.pythonbind31'

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError pythonbind31 ?

Comment: I already figured it out, i forgot to add cache path to environment, thank you all the same!